# Main activity Layout overlays SettingsActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am currently trying to develop an android application which should have Settings. How far I am informed I should use a SettingsActivity.

Mine looks currently like this:

```
package de.nocompany.myname.gw2companion;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.*;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
        int horizontalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int verticalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) + 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        getListView().setPadding(horizontalMargin, topMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_bar, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, that my preferences are not practically usable, because my MainActivity layout is shown above the settings. I have searched a lot for this, but still I cannot find an answer which satisfies my needs. A lot of guys said that you could use wrap the SettingsActivity with Layouts and Stuff, but to my knowledge this is not Good Practice programming which I am trying to do. And I know this is pretty near at the Google example, but I am currently starting to develop the application so this will be replaced! Thx in advance!

EDIT: Replaced the code with the new issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this is an annoying one! I ran into the same issue - The pattern used on the Android Developer site is dated to the days of API 10. My example below demonstrates how to implement Preferences using a modern Activity/Fragment design pattern.

**pref_general.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListPreference
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/pref_sort_label"
        android:key="@string/pref_sort_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_sort_favorite"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_sort_values"
        android:entries="@array/pref_sort_options" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="pref_sort_options">
        <item>@string/pref_sort_label_popular</item>
        <item>@string/pref_sort_label_rating</item>
        <item>@string/pref_sort_label_favorite</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="pref_sort_values">
        <item>@string/pref_sort_popular</item>
        <item>@string/pref_sort_rating</item>
        <item>@string/pref_sort_favorite</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="pref_sort_label">Sort Order</string>
<string name="pref_sort_label_popular">Most Popular</string>
<string name="pref_sort_label_rating">Top Rated</string>
<string name="pref_sort_label_favorite">Favorites</string>
<string name="pref_sort_key" translatable="false">sort</string>
<string name="pref_sort_popular" translatable="false">popular</string>
<string name="pref_sort_rating" translatable="false">rating</string>
<string name="pref_sort_favorite" translatable="false">favorites</string>
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**app_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleMarginStart="32dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
            implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

        public static String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_sort_key)));
        }

        private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
            preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

            onPreferenceChange(preference,
                    PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                            .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            String stringValue = newValue.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                    preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
                }
            }
            else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my failure! After reading apelosoczi's answer I found out that in my app bar, I had an include with my main layout. Now after I declared my own app_bar for this it works! But now I have to add padding over the subsettings :( which does not work currently[image: ![Failure]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcpZj.png)

Comment: what do you mean ? can you post a screen shot ? add a comment when you do - I would be glad to help you with this. Does your container overlap the toolbar? This is why I use a linear layout.

Comment: thought so, fit this xml attribute into the container which your fragment resides in: `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`. On phones this is equal to 56dp, its another value on tablets.. cant remember what though. Use this in your apps in the future, always ! If this solves your problem, please accept my answer to close this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @apelsoczi I had to change to your solution, because I had no container like you can see above. Now I get an empty display when copying your code!

Comment: is it still blank when you rotate your phone? do you have this on github to take a full examination ?

Comment: Now it works! Combined your answer with another one. I will upload it when the basic functions of the app are done.